# Query to get Manager EmployeeID given Managername

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Could someone show me
How do I find managerid here. 
each manager is also an employee and has ID

[image]

Comment: Use `inner join/self join` on table by splinting the  `manager1`

Comment: this is very basic sql query for self join, just search on google, you can easily found the same as example with manger and employee

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the table to itself based on the Manager1 column matching a combination of the FirstName and LastName columns contacted together.

The main table in the query will have the employee's information, you'll then join the table to itself. The join table will be where we get the ManagerID from. Make sure to use a Left Join here because there is bound to be an employee in the table that doesn't have a manager

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Manager1, m.EmployeeID as ManagerID
FROM Employee e
  LEFT JOIN Employee m ON e.Manager1 = m.FirstName + ' ' + m.LastName
```

Comment: There's also a cycle: John Smith -> Jon Doe -> Mike Test -> John Smith. Oh well, I guess it doesn't change the answer.